# How to remove a false-installation which has no archive for it without re-install?

Tags: uninstall, archive, purge

I'm very new here and not an advanced Ubuntu user, so please have mercy with my possible incompetence.

I tried to remove stremio after a failure installation:

```
sudo apt-get remove stremio
```

Output was:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package stremio needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Is there a way to remove it entirely without reinstalling ? Thanks for answers!

Edit: Hi thanks for helping me!
I tried the command

```py
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all stremio
```

I got the following output:

```
dpkg: Waring: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: Warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal  
(Reading database ... 225876 files and directories currently installed
.)
Removing stremio (4.4.116-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/stremio.perm: line 7: cd: purge):/opt/stremio/icons: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package stremio (--purge): 
 installed stremio package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
xdg-desktop-menu: file '/opt/stremio/smartcode-stremio.desktop' does not exist
/var/lib/dpkg/info/stremio.postinst: line 7: cd /opt/stremio/icons: No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed stremio package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 stremio
```

I'm so sorry for my bad formatting/coding skills, hope you see more or less the problem. I guess, there is no other option. I'll have to first reinstall stremio and then remove it...
By the way, I'm working with ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

thank you guys for help anyways! Cheers!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? How was the application installed? Where and how are you looking for it? You need to give a lot more info to get any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the package removal by using low-level command:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all stremio
```

See [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) for details.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me!
I tried the command but it is unable to remove correctly. I got the following output:

Comment: Run `sudo mkdir -p /opt/stremio/icons` and retry.

Comment: I tried and got this:  
  
```dpkg: Warning: ignoring request to remove stremio which isn't installed```

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks man, this fixed my issue